# Exception in thread "WindowsNativeRunloopThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init> when I execute a .jar file

Tags: java, javafx, jar, nullpointerexception, nosuchmethoderror

This evening, I downloaded a `.jar` file from [Jsqlquiz website](http://jsqlquiz.fr/start/). However, when I try to execute it in the terminal, I have these two displayed exceptions (I'm on **Windows 10**) :

> Exception in thread "WindowsNativeRunloopThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.staticScreen_getScreens(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.initScreens(Screen.java:412)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Application.java:152)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

and

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.getAdapterOrdinal(D3DPipeline.java:205)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.assignScreensAdapters(QuantumToolkit.java:695)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runToolkit(QuantumToolkit.java:313)
>           at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$startup$10(QuantumToolkit.java:258)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Application.java:153)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>           at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
>           at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

I check my java's versions to see if I have a bad/old one, but all is on date :

- `JDK 13.0.1`
- `JRE 1.8.0_241`
- `JavaFX 11.0.2`

I found answers on this forum but none helped me. :

- Write `java -jar filename.jar` in a `.bat` file and execute it.
- Extract the folder and try to run it.
- Place `jdk-13.0.1\bin` and `Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin` above the `Common_Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` (I deleted it finally, it was the easiest way to try to fix my problem).

If anyone here thinks they can help me, tell me! :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after hours spent fixing my problem, I finally found it for myself!

For all those who have the same problem, follow what I will say:

- There must be ONLY `one version` of Java on your pc (wether it's the `JDK` or `JRE`). So, only keep the java version you want and try to compile your file with `java -jar fileName.jar` and it should work.

I myself had the JDK and the JRE, both added to the path of the `environment variables`. So the error came from here.

The only thing I don't understand is why the JRE created a problem during the execution when I had put the path of the JDK above.